# Way to view remote desktop connected in LAN in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to view the remote desktop ( not need to control ) using C# in an application.
Remote Desktop allows only one session by default at a time to connect through.

I made a search and got this [link1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET)
and all other materials i got in initial searches are similar to that

But by using that code remote session is locked.

How to achieve it without the remote system is getting locked.
Please help on this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run a [VNC server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) on the PC and access the desktop through a VNC client.

There are C# libraries available for the VNC protocol, this is the first one that came up on my Google search: [VncSharp](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/).